# IntelliJ Idea adding `providedCompile` dependencies in the provided scope

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I am working on a spring boot application, created from the spring initializer and working on IntelliJ Idea 2017.3.4 and Gradle 4.5.1, and there is a need to make a `.war` deployment. For this, I have added the `war` plugin to the Gradle configuration and I have changed the dependencies from

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    ...}
```

to

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'){
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    providedCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    ...}
```

as mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html) . The war deploys perfectly but my development run configurations are broken due to dependencies not found. I have found that this is because Idea(or Gradle, idk) has decided that `providedCompile` dependencies must be scoped as `provided`. But the war plugin docs [mention](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html#sec:war_dependency_management) clearly that the `providedCompile` and `providedRuntime` has the same scopes as `compile` and `runtime`.

How can I fix this? I have tried setting the scopes to compile manually and things got fixed but this is overwritten by Gradle all the time. Is there a non-hacky solution to this?

Any help is appreciated!